# animation bones not working

Tags: animation

I am not sure if this is suppose to happen but Is it suppose to not add the back bones?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *"...but the other bones aren't you know here."* Which other bones? Which back bones do you mean?

Comment: Yes i mean the two back bones

Comment: it had more bones but i removed them and replaced them with only two